# Create tkinter Labels, Buttons, ... in a class

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am trying to improve my structure of tkinter apps.

Therefore, I tried the OOP approach mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application/17470842#17470842) thread.

I tried to play around with it, but couldn't get much further than the example code. I just need a status bar and a main body, but I am unable to display anything (e.g. a `Label`, `Frame`, `Canvas`, `Button`, `...`) in the statusbar/main class.

This is what I currently have:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Statusbar(tk.Frame):
    #create Labels, Buttons,...

class Main(tk.Frame):
    #create Labels, Buttons,...


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.statusbar = Statusbar(self)
        self.main = Main(self)
        self.statusbar.grid()
        self.main.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Maybe you can point me in the right direction or show me a simple example. Thank you.

***EDIT: Trying to be more specific:***

I have worked with tkinter/python a bit. I just don't know how to proceed with the proposed OOP structure from the above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application/17470842#17470842).
I can't get anything inside the `Statusbar` and `Main` class to work (like: creating a label, a button, and so on). So, if you could show me a simple example to create anything in those classes, I'd be good to go.

Comment: @X_841 ***"can't get anything inside the `Statusbar`"***: As it stands, `class Statusbar` is a invalid class defenition. Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) and extend to a valid class defenition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that should give you the general idea:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Statusbar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        lbl1 = tk.Label(self, text='Status1', fg='yellow', bg='blue')
        lbl1.pack(side='left')
        lbl2 = tk.Label(self, text='Status2', fg='white', bg='green')
        lbl2.pack(side='left')


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        txt = tk.Text(self, width=15, height=5)
        txt.insert(tk.END, 'Hello world')
        txt.pack()


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.statusbar = Statusbar(self)
        self.main = Main(self)

        self.statusbar.grid()
        self.main.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).grid()
    root.mainloop()
```